# Arago spot on terrestrial object

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, astronomy, diffraction

Here is a question that occurred to me considering Fresnel's theory and Arago spot:

Is there a bright spot on the surface of the moon in a lunar eclipse?

If No Why?

If Yes,  have we ever make an attempt to observe it?

Comment: Related on [astronomy.se]: [Arago Spot in the Shadows of Celestial Bodies](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/arago-spot-in-the-shadows-of-celestial-bodies).